# proxy anonymity level, what is the tehnical difference ? (specific example from hide my name)

Tags: vpn, anonymity, openvpn

By using hidemy name I can check for a proxy if it is up or down, and also check the `anonymity` level [using the app.](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-checker/) A sample result looks like this:

```
IP address      Port    Country, City   Speed    Type       Anonymity
72.195.114.169  4145    United States   1476 мс  Socks 4/5  High
```

`Ànonymity` can range from `High` to `none` including, `High` `Average` `Low` and `none`

An example of proxy lists provided by hidemy name can [be found here](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?anon=4#list).

What are the technical differences between a `High` `Average` and `Low` anonymity ? Is there a any documents that explain the specific differences in packets being sent? Or for example if I am connecting to a website through the anonymous vpn at which level the endpoint can understand that I am ON a vpn ? If the anonymity is high for example, will the site owners(end point) understand?

Comment: You'd have to ask those who provides the description. There's no universal scale for this.

Comment: I've reverted your edit where you added another question. Please don't make your question a moving target. And if you have more questions please ask these as new ones.

Comment: The system has automatically blocked you from asking questions. It is not something a mod did.

Comment: @schroeder for how long ? I also dont want to create a new account and spam new questions, this has been a mistake

Comment: Please contact them, @schroeder

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th#:~:text=If%20you're%20blocked%20from,months%20after%20your%20last%20question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a any documents that explain the specific differences in packets being sent?

What the rating means is explained on the very site you link to. To cite from the paragraph [Anonymity categories that are in our proxy list:](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?anon=4#list):

> - **No anonymity**: The remote server knows your IP address and knows that you are using a proxy.
> - **Low anonymity**: The remote server does not know your IP, but knows that you are using a proxy.
> - **Average anonymity**: The remote server knows that you are using a proxy and thinks that it knows your IP, but it is not yours (these are
>   usually multi-network proxies that show the remote server the incoming
>   interface as REMOTE_ADDR).
> - **High anonymity**: The remote server does not
>   know your IP, and it has no direct evidence that you are using a
>   proxy. These are anonymous proxies.

Basically there are two major points here which lower the anonymity from High.

- The server knows your IP address:
  Since the access is through a proxy this can only be the case if the proxy, the source IP of the traffic to the server is the proxy. Thus your original IP address can only be seen if the proxy forwards it explicitly to the server, like in a [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header.
- The server knows that a proxy is in use:
  This can be the case because the proxy adds specific HTTP headers. But it can also be that the proxy is on a known list of proxies. For example the source IP addresses of many VPN providers or Tor nodes are known, so that servers can simply lookup the IP address to check its reputation. Similar the server might assume that it is a proxy (or VPN) if access comes from known hosting or cloud providers.

Comment: If the answer is found in the available documentation, FAQ, or the support page of the service, just post the links in the comment field. We can't be a replacement for basic research. If the link was difficult to find, then sure.